# $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']

Tags: ajax, php

Здравствуете, для определения Ajax запроса на сервере использую вот такой код:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    // Если к нам идёт Ajax запрос, то ловим его
    echo 'Это ajax запрос!';
    exit;
}
//Если это не ajax запрос
echo 'Это не ajax запрос!';
```

Вопрос с последним условием `strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'`, зачем оно, какие ещё значения может принимать `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']` и что они означают ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такой вопрос как-то задавался на [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768448/why-use-strtolower-to-verify-serverhttp-x-requested-with).

Если говорить в двух словах, то заголовки, начинающиеся с "X-", считаются нестандартными и разными фреймворками\языками могут посылаться по-разному. В случае с ajax запросом, на сервер может прилететь значение как `xmlHttpRequest`, так и `XMLHttpRequest`. Приведя его к нижнему регистру, вы имеете более гибкий вариант проверки. Все это есть по ссылке выше, а также описаны варианты злонамеренного использования подобных заголовков, почему и требуются дополнительные проверки.